# creating apprehension of such contact

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, legalese

> Battery is a criminal offense involving unlawful physical contact,
>   distinct from assault which is the act of **creating apprehension of
>   such contact.** -Wikipedia

I searched online to find the difference between battery and assault, and rather left, being more confused.

What does 'creating apprehension of such contact' mean?

So battery doesn't accompany the physical contact but instead trigger the fear or threat of the physical contact?

If it is, I'm even more confused because, as I know, batter means to hit something.

Comment: source - [***Battery (crime)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28crime%29)

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer to rewrite:

> Battery is a criminal offense involving unlawful **physical contact**, which is different from **assault** (the act of creating **apprehension** of such contact).

According to Wikipedia, [***assault***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault):

> In common law, assault is the act of creating apprehension of an imminent harmful or offensive contact with a person.

And the definition of [***apprehension***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/apprehension):

> 4) an anxious feeling of foreboding; dread

So your example is saying that *battery* is the physical contact in a crime, while *assault* is the act of creating fear of imminent contact or harm.

Comment: Correction: Assault is not that fear; it is _the act of creating_ that fear.